# This server's certificate chain is incomplete

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

After running a test on [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/), I got `This server's certificate chain is incomplete`. Later I read in orange: `Chain issues   Incomplete, Contains anchor`.

I tried to understand what was wrong and read about the subject, but I don't succeed to see what is wrong and how to find the cause of the issue.

If anyone would mind to give me some steps I could do to find the problem, I would be glad !

**EDIT for further readers:**

The issue was that I had 2 intermediate certificates. I had to copy/paste each of them in one single file and use that file as the whole intermediate certificate.

Comment: Would anyone mind to tell me what is wrong with my question ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clients are expected to have the root certificate already in their list of trusted certificates.

Your own certificate is at the other end of the chain but between these two certificates there are typically one or more intermediate certificates.

As clients are not expected to know about these intermediate certificates you should configure your server to not only present its own certificate but also any intermediate certificates.
This allows the client to have the whole chain available and be able to validate that it ends at one of its trusted certificates.

Comment: I thought that I did it already. Let me check. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Ok, I had 2 intermediate certificates, I had to put them one after the other in the same file. I didn't know that. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Sharcoux how did you do that?

Comment: @Goatmale How they concatenated the files?

Comment: Yep - looks like this site will do it. https://certificatechain.io/

Comment: @Goatmale Or you can just `cat file1 file2 >combined` or copy/paste the contents into a single file or whichever method you prefer of combining the contents of two text files.

Comment: https://comodosslstore.com/blog/installing-comodo-positivessl-certificate-on-nginx.html - Step-by-step description of how to do what answer above describes, but for a specific TLS cert vendor. Steps are general enough to adapt for your own cert from another provider.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool to automate the procedure of producing a bundle of correctly chained certificates. https://github.com/zakjan/cert-chain-resolver (I'm the author.)

Usage:

```
cert-chain-resolver -o domain.bundle.pem domain.pem
```

- domain.pem is your input certificate
- domain.bundle.pem is the certificate bundle, that you can use in your web server configuration